# Parse Nester JSON in Python

Tags: python, arrays, json

So I am stumped here...I am trying to filter a JSON result from an API and am having issues finding the nested "playerID" in the below, and outputting the whole JSON block up to "type"

**JSON**

```
{
    "included": [
    {
        "type": "participant",
        "id": "efb753a7-bc6b-4cf0-925a-df4693b51690",
        "attributes": {
            "actor": "",
            "shardId": "pc-na",
            "stats": {
                "DBNOs": 0,
                "assists": 0,
                "boosts": 0,
                "damageDealt": 21.78,
                "deathType": "byplayer",
                "headshotKills": 0,
                "heals": 1,
                "killPlace": 69,
                "killPoints": 1204,
                "killPointsDelta": -12.1259718,
                "killStreaks": 0,
                "kills": 0,
                "lastKillPoints": 0,
                "lastWinPoints": 0,
                "longestKill": 0,
                "mostDamage": 0,
                "name": "AshTrayyyyyyyy",
                "playerId": "account.a6e705568e1e490189d59606892765a9",
                "revives": 0,
                "rideDistance": 0,
                "roadKills": 0,
                "teamKills": 0,
                "timeSurvived": 293,
                "vehicleDestroys": 0,
                "walkDistance": 197.17308,
                "weaponsAcquired": 0,
                "winPlace": 28,
                "winPoints": 1152,
                "winPointsDelta": -4.64524174
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "participant",
        "id": "e916ce2e-aea4-4806-9aa1-449113df793c",
        "attributes": {
            "actor": "",
            "shardId": "pc-na",
            "stats": {
                "DBNOs": 0,
                "assists": 0,
                "boosts": 1,
                "damageDealt": 54.3429337,
                "deathType": "byplayer",
                "headshotKills": 0,
                "heals": 7,
                "killPlace": 56,
                "killPoints": 1185,
                "killPointsDelta": -5.10656166,
                "killStreaks": 0,
                "kills": 0,
                "lastKillPoints": 0,
                "lastWinPoints": 0,
                "longestKill": 0,
                "mostDamage": 0,
                "name": "PanzerCheneyJr",
                "playerId": "account.380f694417594236a8dc9f5dcc0b0ed5",
                "revives": 0,
                "rideDistance": 1869.12939,
                "roadKills": 0,
                "teamKills": 0,
                "timeSurvived": 1476,
                "vehicleDestroys": 0,
                "walkDistance": 2950.75659,
                "weaponsAcquired": 0,
                "winPlace": 10,
                "winPoints": 1184,
                "winPointsDelta": 15.2799187
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "roster",
        "id": "f876ef81-bd51-494b-9cf0-49d4da725ff0",
        "attributes": {
            "shardId": "pc-na",
            "stats": {
                "rank": 40,
                "teamId": 11
            },
            "won": "false"
        },
        "relationships": {
            "participants": {
                "data": [
                    {
                        "type": "participant",
                        "id": "0c936615-eb39-42f8-bbe3-5b17bcf6c7dd"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "participant",
                        "id": "62a6ed31-f5bf-4b0a-b867-8260774dcb90"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "team": {
                "data": null
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "participant",
        "id": "8b63d4d9-a673-48d8-9e56-cfe2109044d8",
        "attributes": {
            "actor": "",
            "shardId": "pc-na",
            "stats": {
                "DBNOs": 1,
                "assists": 1,
                "boosts": 5,
                "damageDealt": 466.477539,
                "deathType": "byplayer",
                "headshotKills": 0,
                "heals": 4,
                "killPlace": 3,
                "killPoints": 1105,
                "killPointsDelta": 54.3647232,
                "killStreaks": 0,
                "kills": 4,
                "lastKillPoints": 0,
                "lastWinPoints": 0,
                "longestKill": 74,
                "mostDamage": 0,
                "name": "JustFallen",
                "playerId": "account.1ea2035542e44f37bb2b7a3679a91fcc",
                "revives": 0,
                "rideDistance": 1945.68457,
                "roadKills": 0,
                "teamKills": 0,
                "timeSurvived": 1561,
                "vehicleDestroys": 0,
                "walkDistance": 2272.8418,
                "weaponsAcquired": 0,
                "winPlace": 4,
                "winPoints": 1179,
                "winPointsDelta": 28.698019
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And for Python this is where I'm completely stumped. What I am trying to do is return the whole participant block, and everything nested inside of it. But I need to filter by the "playerID" under attributes -> stats.

Here's the Python that I've tried...

**Python**

```
included = (data['included'])
included = json.dumps(included)
input_dict = json.loads(included)
print(playerid)
for d in input_dict:
    for key, value in d.iteritems():
        print (key, value)
output_dict = [x for x in input_dict if x['playerID'] == playerid]
output_json = json.dumps(output_dict)
print(output_json)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What you pasted here isn't valid JSON. It looks like `included` is an array of dicts, but there's no `]` anywhere to close the array.

Comment: Meanwhile, why are you doing a `dumps` just to do a `loads` on the resulting string?

Comment: I just copied a snip of the whole JSON, it was way too long to post.
I had issues when I didn't do the dump then load...I know it's not valid JSON, but that's how I'm pulling it from the API, nothing I can do.

Comment: I don’t believe there is any data you could possibly have where a dumps followed by an immediately loads solved anything. That’s just waving a stick around and hoping it’s a magic wand. And it can’t be true that your actual data isn’t valid JSON, or you couldn’t dump it and load it, so what you’ve posted here is not a valid example of your problem. Please read [mcve] in the help to see how to create a question that’s answerable without guesswork (which usually ends up with an answer that doesn’t answer your actual problem).

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a good idea how to dump and load the JSON, so here is the part that filters:

```
playerid = 'account.380f694417594236a8dc9f5dcc0b0ed5'
new_data = [x
            for x in data['included']
            if x['type'] == 'participant' and
               x['attributes']['stats']['playerId'] == playerid]
```